# fit_generator in keras v.2.2.4 and python 3.6.8 not working

Tags: python-3.x, keras

**fit_generator**

*works* fine in:
`Python 3.6.5
 Keras 2.1.6`

But *doesn't* in:
`Python 3.6.8. 
 Keras 2.2.4`

It gets stack forever in the 1st epoch (I can see it with verbose=1).

Did anyone experience this? If so, do you know how to make it work with the newer versions of python and keras?

Thank you

Comment: Updating keras and tensorflow can be a huge hassle, if there isn't any functionality that you absolutely need in 2.2.4 I would always stick with the version that I know works. That said, can you share more of your code?